# Running integrated Angular project and Spring boot with Https

Tags: java, angular, typescript, spring-boot, ssl-certificate

I have an angular application which is integrated with spring boot and it requires maven to build the angular project and create a single jar which can be executed by using simple java -jar command. The problem is that I have to run my angular app with Https. I know that to run standalone angular app on https one have to provide ssl flag with ng serve command but as my frontend app is integrated with spring boot and a jar is created in the end. So should I provide ssl configuration in spring boot or angular project?
This is what I have tried up-till now

- Provided ssl configuration in spring boot
- Provided same ssl configuration in spring boot and angular app.
- Provided ssl configuration in angular app.

Getting the same error :

> This site can’t provide a secure connectionlocalhost uses an unsupported protocol.
>   ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH

My angular.json config:

```
 "serve": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
      "options": {
        "browserTarget": "dqUi:build",
        "proxyConfig": "proxy.config.json",
        "ssl": true,
        "sslCert": "../src/main/resources/https-frontend.p12"
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "browserTarget": "dqUi:build:production"
        },
        "dev": {
          "browserTarget": "dqUi:build:dev"
        },
        "qa": {
          "browserTarget": "dqUi:build:production"
        }
      }
    }
```

Spring boot configuration:

```
server.ssl.key-alias=https-frontend
server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
server.ssl.key-password=etisalat
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:https-frontend.p12
```

Anybody have faced a similar problem? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi @Farrukh Ahmed, hope you have solved the issue. I am in the same situation. Can you please suggest.

Comment: Hi @JoginderMalik yes I have solved the issue. Can you please elaborate what issue you are facing and I will be more than happy to help.

Comment: Hi @Farrukh Ahmed thank you for your reply. i have an application developed in spring boot. it is running on 8080. I have another angular8 app which is running on 4200 port. Both apps are able to communicate with each other properly. Now i want my app/domain should be ssl enabled. So my question is do we need separate ssl certificate for both apps or it would be enough to configure at spring boot side. I will generate letsEncrypt certificate.

Comment: Can anyone please explain how to solve this issue? thanks in advance